# The 'say' command is not working with the 'at' command

Tags: macos, command-line, at, say

I'm running macOS 10.13.5, and I want the Mac to say something, such as the current time, with the `at` command for the specified time.

I have already loaded the `atrun` daemon, and the following command is working:

```
at now + 1 minute
echo "blah" > /tmp/test.txt
```

But when I use a `say` command with the `at` command, it does nothing:

```
at now + 1 minute
say 'hello'
```

I would like to know what happened. Is there a log or something I can do to find out?

Comment: @JakeGould I think it's more likely to do with the `say` command not being part of the user's login session (specifically its Mach bootstrap context). The `atrun` daemon runs as root, and runs the command (e.g. `say`) under the appropriate user ID, but without switching context, and thus doesn't have access to the speakers. This is all quite badly documented, but there's some info [here](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2016/03/25/running-processes-in-os-x-as-the-logged-in-user-from-outside-the-users-account/).

Comment: @GordonDavisson I have tried with launchctl asuser $(id -u username) /usr/bin/say hello as the task to run, still not working.

Comment: I have tried to write a plist file which use WatchPaths to start. What I expected is when I write some text to /tmp/say.txt, the lauchd will run `say -f /tmp/say.txt`, but it failed.

Comment: What is strange that when run cron job, one can wrap `say` in a .sh file and everything works. But I tried this with `at` command, failed.